# SerialPort.BytesToRead always evaluated to 0 even though it isn't

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am interfacing a scale to a computer through a serial port. I check the value SerialPort.BytesToRead for when it reaches 0 inside a loop. However the loop exits even though BytesToRead is not equal to 0. I can't post a screenshot as I am a new user but by going through debug I can see that BytesToRead is in fact not 0.

This results in my data not being read entirely. I have tried for different expressions such as `_port.BytesToRead > 0` but the result is the same. Even assigning the value of BytesToRead to a variable gives a 0. Without the loop ReadExisting doesn't return all the data sent from the scale so I don't really have a choice. ReadLine doesn't work either. So why is BytesToRead always 0?

```
private void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        {
            var input = string.Empty;
            // Reads the data one by one until it reaches the end
            do
            {
                input += _port.ReadExisting();
            } while (_port.BytesToRead != 0);

            _scaleConfig = GenerateConfig(input);

            if (ObjectReceived != null)
                ObjectReceived(this, _scaleConfig);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is normal, a debugging artifact.  Your code cannot work, you are not making sure that you got all of the bytes in the response.  Typically ReadLine() works, if the NewLine property matches with what the scale sends.

Comment: The thing is that the scale sends multiple lines of data at once so I would still have to keep it inside a loop to get all the lines. How would I make sure that I have reached the end of the data? I am trying to generalize this so that it's possible to change scale without having to change this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My boss figured it out. Here's the code.

```
private void PortDataReceived2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bytesToRead = _port.BytesToRead;
        _portDataReceived.Append(_port.ReadExisting());

        // Buffer wasn't full. We are at the end of the transmission.
        if (bytesToRead < _port.DataBits)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Final Data received: {0}", _portDataReceived));
            IScalePropertiesBuilder scaleReading = null;

            scaleReading = GenerateConfig(_portDataReceived.ToString());
            _portDataReceived.Clear();


            if (ObjectReceived != null)
            {
                ObjectReceived(this, scaleReading);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original code was strange because I don't see anyway for the code to know if the buffer is empty because your code has emptied it, or because the device hasn't sent yet.  (This seems to be a fundamental problem in your design:  you want to read until you get all the bytes, but only after you read all the bytes can you figure out how many there should have been).

Your later code is even stranger, because DataBits is the serial configuration for number of bits per byte (between 5 and 8 inclusive)--only in RS232 can a byte be less than 8 bits.

That said, I have been seeing very strange behavior around BytesToRead.  It appears to me that it is almost completely unreliable and must get updated only after it would be useful.  There is a note on MSDN about it being inconsistent, but it doesn't include the case of it being inexplicably 0, which I have seen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you are running the debugger it's going slow enough that there are in fact bytes to read, but when you running it without the debugger and therefore there are no breakpoints happening, it ends up exiting the loop before the device on the serial port has time to send the data. Most likely the ReadExisting will read all the data on the port, and then exit immediately because no new data is on the port. Perhaps to alleviate the problem you can put a small wait (perhaps with Thread.Sleep()) between reading the data and checking to see if there is more data by checking the value of BytesToRead.  Although you should probably be looking at the data that you are reading in order to determine when you have infact read all the necessary data for whatever it is you are trying to receive.

Comment: Putting a Thread.Sleep() before reading the data does work but I am trying to do without it for efficiency. For the scale that I am using right now I can easily figure out the end of the data I am receiving but I want to make this as abstract as possible so that I don't have to change this code if I ever need to change scale.